# TinyMce Reloads on toolbar click

Tags: jquery, .net, tinymce, tinymce-4

Does anyone know why is this happening here is a video screen record of issue.
[video](https://imgur.com/a/rPv7EvP)
This is the init code
Currently, Im upgrading Tinymce into 4.7.12 from 4.5 in this process I find out several things are changed in some of the plugins I used previously and onchange events. I used JqueryTinyMce to init that.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#<%=_questionText.ClientID%>').tinymce({
            setup: function (editor) {
                editor.on('init', function (e) {
                    $('#' + e.target.id + '_ifr').removeAttr('title');
                });
            },
            // Location of TinyMCE script
            script_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/Resources/tinymce_4.7.12/tinymce.min.js")%>',
               height: 246,
               //cleanup_on_startup:true,
               remove_redundant_brs: true,
               forced_root_block: false,
               branding: false,
               width: 1035,
               relative_urls: false,
               remove_script_host: false,
               // Drop lists for link/image/media/template dialogs
               //template_external_list_url: 'lists/template_list.js',
               external_link_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=documents")%>',
               external_image_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=images")%>',
                media_external_list_url: '<%=ResolveUrl("~/ContentList.aspx?contentType=video")%>',
                plugins: [
                    "image charmap textcolor code upload advlist link <%= (IsHorizontalRuleEnabled? "hr" : "") %> table paste lists"
                ],
                toolbar1: "bold italic underline strikethrough superscript subscript | bullist numlist indent outdent link | <%= (IsHorizontalRuleEnabled? "hr" : "") %> image upload table | charmap code | forecolor backcolor  | styleselect fontselect fontsizeselect ",
                table_default_attributes: {
                    cellpadding: '5px'
                },
                table_default_styles: {
                    width: '50%'
                },
                paste_as_text: true,
                menubar: false,
               init_instance_callback: "tinyMCEInitialized_<%=ClientID%>",
               default_link_target: "_blank",
               //Cause contents to be written back to base textbox on change
               onchange_callback: function (ed) { ed.save(); },
               gecko_spellcheck: true,
               fontsize_formats: "8px 10px 12px 14px 16px 18px 20px 24px 36px"
           });

        //fix for incorrect user input html
        var ok = $('a[id$=_okBtn]');
        ok.attr('data-href', ok.attr('href'));
        ok.removeAttr('href');
        ok.attr('onclick', 'okButtonClick()');
    });
```

Tool bar not reloads and does its work